# Is it possible that $\text{lcm}(zx, zy)$ exists but $\text{lcm}(x, y)$ not?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it possible to find an example of an integral domain $D$ and a pair of non-zero elements $x$ and $y$ in $D$ such that $\text{lcm}(zx, zy)$ exists for some non-zero element $z$ in $D$ but $\text{lcm}(x, y)$ does not?

Definition of least common divisor (lcm):
Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a commutative ring $R$. A common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is an element $m$ of $R$ such that there exist elements $x$ and $y$ of $R$ such that $ax = by = m$. A least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is a common multiple $m$ of $a$ and $b$ that is minimal in the sense that for any other common multiple $n$ of $a$ and $b$, $n=zm$ for some $z$ in $R$.

Comment: @mvw I have added that to the question.

Comment: By now you asked three questions on lcm/gcd. That's not a problem, but it'd be nice if you provided some context to this. What are you trying to achieve over all?

Comment: @quid Nothing. I just don’t have anything better to do now.

Comment: @quid A few days ago I accidentally spotted a mistake in my old lecture notes of the abstract algebra course which I took as a undergrad student. It wrote: in an integral domain, $\gcd(x, y)=\gcd(x, z)=1$ implies $\gcd(x, yz)=1$. The lecture got this wrong because he used the identity $\gcd(zx, zy)=z\gcd(x, y)$ without checking the existence of $\gcd(zx, zy)$. Since I have nothing to do recentlly, I decided to explore a little bit on this topic.

Comment: This type of comment was exactly the type of information that I was looking for. Thank you, it helps me contextualize the questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M$ be a lowest common multiple of $zx$ and $zy$. It's clear that $z$ divides $M$, say $M=zm$, so we can try and see whether $m$ satisfies the properties for being a lowest common multiple of $x$ and $y$.

First, $M=azx=bzy$, so $m=ax=by$.

Now suppose $r$ is a common multiple of $x$ and $y$. Then $zr$ is a common multiple of $zx$ and $zy$; therefore $M=zm$ divides $zr$. Hence $m$ divides $r$.

Comment: Can we assume that $z$ has multiplicative inverse?

Comment: @Javi I'm not assuming that; since $z$ divides $M$, we have $M=mz$ for some $m$; then $M/z=m$ in the quotient field. I'll rewrite, so to avoid division.

Comment: @egreg: Does $az=bz$ imply $a=b$?

Comment: @celtschk The question assumes $z\ne0$ (and being in a domain).